# wildfly 10 database login module

Tags: security, containers, wildfly, jaas

I am trying to get the database login module to work with my project in the Wildfly 10 container.

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.examsmyantra.com/article/119/javaee/form-based-login-authentication-in-javaee7-with-wildfly-and-mysql

And it's kinda working.

I have an EAR project with an EJB module and a Web module (war). The war is not containing the EJB it's accessing it using the remote lookup.

So when I acces an restricted part of the WAR I am correctly send to the login form (`j_security_check`).

When I login, I can see the restricted part.
Even when I log in a servet which user I am and check if I have a specif role it works.
Servlet code:

```
final String username = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
logger.info("Current username acourding to the WEB: {}", request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
logger.info("User has Role user acourding to the WEB: {}", request.isUserInRole("user"));
logger.info("User has Role admin acourding to the WEB: {}", request.isUserInRole("admin"));
```

Log:

```
INFO  [com.example.web.servlet.DatasetServlet] (default task-5) Current username acourding to the WEB: user
INFO  [com.example.web.servlet.DatasetServlet] (default task-5) User has Role user acourding to the WEB: true
INFO  [com.example.web.servlet.DatasetServlet] (default task-5) User has Role admin acourding to the WEB: true
INFO [com.example.business.remote.DatasetEJB] (default task-5) Get active dataset for the user: user
```

but when I enter the EJB bean like this:

```
final String dataset = remote.getActiveDataset(); // this is still the servlet (WAR)
```

EJB:

```
final String username = this.ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();

logger.info("Get active dataset for the user: " + username);
logger.info("User has role 'user' {}", this.ejbContext.isCallerInRole("user"));
logger.info("User has role 'admin' {}", this.ejbContext.isCallerInRole("admin"));
```

I get:

```
Exception caught: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: policyRegistration -- service jboss.naming.context.java.policyRegistration

PBOX00326: isCallerInRole processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PBOX00071: Failed to instantiate interface org.jboss.security.authorization.AuthorizationModule class

Exception:=PBOX00071: Failed to instantiate interface org.jboss.security.authorization.AuthorizationModule
```

The Full log shows this:

```
TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: {}
INFO  [com.example.business.remote.DatasetEJB] (default task-5) Get active dataset for the user: user
TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: {}
2016-09-16 22:53:52,724 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00293: Exception caught: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: policyRegistration -- service jboss.naming.context.java.policyRegistration
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper.getPolicyRegistrationFromJNDI(EJBAuthorizationHelper.java:353)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper.isCallerInRole(EJBAuthorizationHelper.java:170)
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.isCallerInRole(SimpleSecurityManager.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.isCallerInRole(EJBComponent.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.context.EJBContextImpl.isCallerInRole(EJBContextImpl.java:115)
    at com.example.business.remote.DatasetEJB.getActiveDataset(DatasetEJB.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    ...
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-09-16 22:53:52,727 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00282: Failed to instantiate class Database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Database from [Module "deployment.ear.ear.business-ejb-assignment-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.instantiateModule(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:326)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.initializeModules(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.authorize(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossAuthorizationManager.internalAuthorization(JBossAuthorizationManager.java:438)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossAuthorizationManager.authorize(JBossAuthorizationManager.java:115)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper.isCallerInRole(EJBAuthorizationHelper.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.isCallerInRole(SimpleSecurityManager.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.isCallerInRole(EJBComponent.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.context.EJBContextImpl.isCallerInRole(EJBContextImpl.java:115)
    at com.example.business.remote.DatasetEJB.getActiveDataset(DatasetEJB.java:225)
    ...
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-09-16 22:53:52,728 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00326: isCallerInRole processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PBOX00071: Failed to instantiate interface org.jboss.security.authorization.AuthorizationModule class
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.instantiateModule(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:336)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.initializeModules(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.authorize(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossAuthorizationManager.internalAuthorization(JBossAuthorizationManager.java:438)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossAuthorizationManager.authorize(JBossAuthorizationManager.java:115)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper.isCallerInRole(EJBAuthorizationHelper.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.isCallerInRole(SimpleSecurityManager.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.isCallerInRole(EJBComponent.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.context.EJBContextImpl.isCallerInRole(EJBContextImpl.java:115)
    at com.example.business.remote.DatasetEJB.getActiveDataset(DatasetEJB.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
... 
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

TRACE [org.jboss.security.audit] (default task-5) [Error]Resource:=[org.jboss.security.authorization.resources.EJBResource:contextMap={roleRefPermissionCheck=true, roleName=user, policyRegistration=null}:method=null:ejbMethodInterface=null:ejbName=DatasetEJB:ejbPrincipal=org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.AccountImpl$AccountPrincipal@36ebcb:MethodRoles=null:securityRoleReferences=[]:callerSubject=Subject:
    Principal: user
    Principal: Roles(members:user,admin)
    Principal: CallerPrincipal(members:user)
:callerRunAs=null:callerRunAs=null:ejbRestrictionEnforcement=false:ejbVersion=2.0];Action=authorization;roleRefPermissionCheck=true;Exception:=PBOX00071: Failed to instantiate interface org.jboss.security.authorization.AuthorizationModule class;roleName=user;Source=org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper;policyRegistration=null;
TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: {}
INFO  [com.example.business.remote.DatasetEJB] (default task-5) User has role 'user' false
```

And I don't understand why.
My guess is that the security domain is correctly configured, because otherwise the war would not be working. So it must have something to do with a missing config in the EJB.

Some additional info:

In the standalone.xml I have these settings:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
   ...
    <default-security-domain value="jdbcejbrick"/>
    <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>
    <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
</subsystem>
```

And

```
<security-domain name="jdbcejbrick" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/poc-ejb-alg"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT a.NAME, 'Roles' FROM AUTHORIZATIONS a LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZATION_USER au on au.AUTHORIZATION_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZATION_USER_GROUP aug on aug.AUTHORIZATION_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN USER_GROUPS ug on aug.GROUP_ID  = ug.ID LEFT JOIN USER_USER_GROUP uug on ug.ID = uug.GROUP_ID LEFT JOIN USERS u on (au.USER_ID = u.ID) or (uug.USER_ID = u.ID) WHERE u.NAME=?"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select PASSWORD from USERS where NAME=?"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <policy-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/poc-ejb-alg"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT a.NAME, 'Roles' FROM AUTHORIZATIONS a LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZATION_USER au on au.AUTHORIZATION_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZATION_USER_GROUP aug on aug.AUTHORIZATION_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN USER_GROUPS ug on aug.GROUP_ID  = ug.ID LEFT JOIN USER_USER_GROUP uug on ug.ID = uug.GROUP_ID LEFT JOIN USERS u on (au.USER_ID = u.ID) or (uug.USER_ID = u.ID) WHERE u.NAME=?"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select PASSWORD from USERS where NAME=?"/>
        </policy-module>
    </authorization>
</security-domain>
```

I have a jboss-ejb3.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF of the EJB

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:sec="urn:security" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-spec-2_0.xsd
      urn:security urn:security"
  version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">

  <assembly-descriptor>

    <sec:security>
      <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
      <sec:security-domain>jdbcejbrick</sec:security-domain>
    </sec:security>
  </assembly-descriptor>

</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

I have an ejb-jar.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF of the EJB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar>
  <assembly-descriptor>

    <security-role>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
  </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

I am feeling that I am real close, so please help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I was rubber ducking here :S
While explaining the problem I realised that it was a policy problem because username was already okay in the EJB

And the error  "Failed to instantiate class Database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" gave me an idea to look at the documentation for policy-module
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Security+subsystem+configuration

```
<policy-module code="PermitAll" flag="required">
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/poc-ejb-alg"/>
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT a.NAME, 'Roles' FROM AUTHORIZATIONS a LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZATION_USER au on au.AUTHORIZATION_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZATION_USER_GROUP aug on aug.AUTHORIZATION_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN USER_GROUPS ug on aug.GROUP_ID  = ug.ID LEFT JOIN USER_USER_GROUP uug on ug.ID = uug.GROUP_ID LEFT JOIN USERS u on (au.USER_ID = u.ID) or (uug.USER_ID = u.ID) WHERE u.NAME=?"/>
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select PASSWORD from USERS where NAME=?"/>
</policy-module>
```

If a Wildfly developer ever read this please validate the standalone config and log a message when something like happens! :D

Hopes this ever helps someone!

Comment: Create a Jira about this if you think the warning/error message is worth it.